# ASP.Net MVC 2 custom membership user role assignments are caching

Tags: caching, asp.net-membership, roles

I'm new to implementing custom membership/roles for ASP.Net MVC 2.  I have membership/roles working in that a user can login successfully and can retrieve their role assignments.  However, if I change their role assignments in the underlying database, those changes are not propagating through to the app.  I removed all role assignments for said user and when they login, they still have the same role assignments they had before I deleted the assignments in the database.

I'm using Entity Framework 4 for user/role retrieval.  I created a test that calls the same code for getting a user by name and this test successfully returns the correct role assignments each time, regardless of what mods I make at the database.  So this rules out any EF cache.

I also removed all caching at the browser level (I'm using Firefox 3.6.8) and I have the same issue.

So, this seems to be a custom membership/role caching issue.  What setting am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

When you say you are using EF for user/role retrieval, do you mean you have a custom provider rolled?  I would look here for possible caching.  At the very least, if you restart the web server does the caching go away?

Comment: Yes, I have a custom provider.  I found this link after my posting and it seems to have solved the problem.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914437/asp-net-mvc-and-role-caching

It seems silly to have a dedicated connection just to check roles, but it solved the problem.

Comment: Hi Tom - I ran into this same issue - do you just instantiate a new context at the the custom role provider?